# show a record in datagridview that is not in the table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010

how to show the record in datagridview when it is not in database and get the date of that record.

for example

in my database i have a record like this

[image]

as you can see john dont have a record in 2/15/2016 and ken dont have a record in 2/16/2016

now in data gridview it should be show like this

[image]

is it posible to get this record? i dont have an idea to do these im realy need help. Im using vb and ms-access as database.

Comment: it's not possible to GET the record but you should be able to determine what needs added by iterating through the list and adding entries where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work in Access?

```
select *, 'absent' 
from (
     select *
     from (select distinct empname from table) n, (select distinct empdate from table) d
     ) sq
where sq.n + '-' + sq.d not in (select empname + '-' + empdate from table)
```

I might not have that just right, but the point is, if you get a cartesian table of all names and dates and then eliminate the ones that appear in your DB, the ones that remain are the absences.